# Sublime text 3 Not showing Tabs at all (Even at double clicking)

Tags: tabs, sublimetext3

i have seen many posts about sublime text 3 not showing files in tabs but almost all of them are about the click on preview feature.

This time i am not getting tabs at all.
I single click a file and i get the preview and by double clicking i open it, that what we expect, but when a file it's opened the tabs are not showing, i know the files are opened because i use `Ctrl + Tab` to change between them, and `Ctrl + w` to close them.

I really need the tabs to work faster so please help me.
[Here it's an image of an opened file with no tab ( Double clicked file )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7e8T.png)

Comment: View menu -> Show Tabs ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto `View`
2. Click `Show Tabs` option

See attached image.

[image]

Comment: Maybe resetting sublime text might work for you. For that, you have to delete your sublime text folder in `AppData\Roaming` (for window user).
For further help you can check this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUL_TLotgTs

***NOTE:*** By resetting it will drop all of you installed packages and setting.

Comment: ms stupid, i already had tried it but i deleted from local app data. Thanks alot.